# Ruby: define a class that returns something other than itself when an instance is called without any methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, presenter

I'm wondering if there's a way to return an object instead of a string when calling an object without any methods.

For instance:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = Bar.new
  end
end
```

Is there any way to define the Foo class so that the following happens:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo #returns @bar
```

In the specific case I'm interested in I'm using a presenter in a Rails view. The presenter sets up one main object and then loads a bunch of related content. The important part looks like this:

```
class ExamplePresenter

  def initialize( id )
    @example = Example.find( id )
  end

  def example
    @example
  end

  ...

end
```

If I want to return the example used by the ExamplePresenter I can call:

```
@presenter = ExamplePresenter.new(1)
@presenter.example
```

It would be nice if I could also return the example object by just calling:

```
@presenter
```

So, is there a way to set a default method to return when an object is called, like to_s but returning an object instead of a string?

Comment: Could you be more specific about where `@presenter` is used? Is this in a view?

Comment: This is in a Rails view, but really I'm interested in just the ruby language related to objects period. I'm curious if there's a way to define a class so that it would return something other than itself when you call it without any methods.

Comment: you can't call a class cause its an object ( you can call `object_id` on class) not a method you might redefine `to_s` or `inspect` methods maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to return the instance of `Example` when you call the `ExamplePresenter` instance. Such a direct mechanism does not exist in any language, and even if it did, it would block all access to the `ExamplePresenter` instance and its methods. So it is not logical.

There is something you can do however. You can make the `ExamplePresenter` class delegate methods to the `Example` instance inside it. Effectively you do not get a real `Example` from `@presenter` but you get an `ExamplePresenter` that passes all eligible methods into its internal `Example` effectively acting in behalf of it.

Some ways of doing this is:

### method_missing

```
class ExamplePresenter
  … # as defined in the question

  def method_missing symbol, *args
    if @example.respond_to?(symbol)
      @example.send(symbol, *args)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

This will pass any method call down to the internal `Example` if the `ExamplePresenter` cannot respond to it. Be careful, you may expose more than you want of the internal `Example` this way, and any method already defined on `ExamplePresenter` cannot be passed along.

You can use additional logic inside `method_missing` to limit exposure or pre/post process the arguments/return values.

### Wrapper methods

You can define wrapper methods on `ExamplePresenter` that do nothing but pass everything to the internal `Example`. This gives you explicit control on how much of it you want to expose.

```
class ExamplePresenter
  … # as before

  def a_method
    @example.a_method
  end
  def another_method(argument, another_argument)
    @example.another_method(argument, another_argument)
  end
end
```

This gets tedious fast, but you can also add logic to alter arguments before passing it along to the `Example` or post process the results.

You can also mix and match the above two methods

### [Delegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) library

There is a library in Ruby stdlib called [**Delegator**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) built exactly for this purpose. You may look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Your first note that "it would block all access to the ExamplePresenter instance" occurred to me about half an hour after I wrote the question... but your suggestions regarding method_missing and wrappers would definitely let me do what I'm looking to do. This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: there's also the forwardable http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/index.html if you only want a few methods.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not recommended, you can do:

```
class Foo
  def self.new
    @bar = Bar.new
  end
end
```

If you actually do need to create an instance of `Foo`, then

```
class << Foo
  alias original_new :new
end

class Foo
  def self.new
    self.original_new # It will not be useful unless you assign this to some variable.
    @bar = Bar.new
  end
end
```